# 'File not found' when integrating React Native with existing project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm having problems integrating React Native into my existing iOS project. When I run the project through Xcode, everything works as expected. However, when I run the project with through the terminal (using command: npx react-native run-ios), I get an error as follows:

```
fatal error: 'React/RCTRootView.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
```

It's not just RCTRootView though, it's all react native imports. The setup is done with npm and cocoapods. If I remove all the import statements in the code, I instead get this error:

```
framework not found CoreModules
```

Steps I've taken:

- I followed the steps on https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps to the letter
- I searched for a long time on similar issues on SO and on the React Native GitHub issues page; none of the suggested solutions work.

The fact that it all works when running through Xcode was quite confusing. I run the same configuration and scheme when running through npx.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer halfway through writing the question, so I thought I might as well post it in case it might save someone some time in the future. It took me a while because the initial error I got wasn't the core problem.

The issue was caused by the fact that I'd forgotten to update the deployment target in the target deployment info (from iOS 9 to iOS 11).

Also some cred to where I found the solution:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26106#issuecomment-600328194